# Picking value from Text Box in jquery by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side

I am having 3 textbox where the ids are

> "ctl00_m_g_8b41d68e_7c2d_49c3_a4b5_316440ad77e1_SpListPicker_SelectionBox", "ctl00_m_g_9b41d68e_7c2d_49c3_a4b5_316440ad77e1_SpListPicker_SelectionBox" and "ctl00_m_g_8a41d68e_7c2d_49c3_a4b5_316440ad77e1_SpListPicker_SelectionBox".

Now the id which is getting generated dynamically, but the "`SpListPicker_SelectionBox`" is constant. 
Now I am having a requirement, `onClick` of a button either of the 3 textbox will have the value, which is to be fetched. How can I get the value of textbox. 
Any help is appreciated. Can we get the value on the like operator? where `ID` like '`%SpListPicker_SelectionBox`' ??

Comment: Why not make the ID be generated in a consistent way? Or use a class?

Comment: because this is getting generated from the sharepoint and i can not do any deployment or code behind changes, i just need to take the values on the Client Side. And class is also getting generated in the same fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $inputs = $('input[id$="SpListPicker_SelectionBox"]')
```

Where `$=` is the [**Attribute Ends With Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Then you can loop through each textbox and get the values like:

```
$inputs.each(function( index ) {
  alert( index + ": " + $(this).val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use attribute selector with `$` ,this fetch all the elements ending with the given string..

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
 $('input[id$="SpListPicker_SelectionBox"]').val()
```

Comment: this is useful, but i need to get the values of all the text boxes which has id like "SpListPicker_SelectionBox". This is giving me 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

you can write Javascript or jquery code runtime by using code while textboxs generated and use exact textbox id associate with jquery statement.